# How to change the destination of outgoing UDP packets?

Tags: windows, networking, vb6, udp, winsock

Windows has this type of thing with TCP packets already (Hosts File), is there a file or application that will allow me to redirect outgoing packets? So if I were sending on port 80, I would be able to redirect it to another ip and maybe another port (not that I need another port).

I'm using winsock in addition with Microsoft VB6 (yes I know old) to send packets to an ip.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hosts file is a way to override the dns server name lookup. It will affect all protocols -including tcp and udp.

It will only override as long as you are sending to a specific name though. If you use the ip address directly instead of a host name, no host name lookup and no hosts file will be involved.

Comment: @Joe: If this answer was the one that helped you solve the problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Can't you place an IP address into the hosts and redirect that?  Or is it only for names?